# Do modern browsers print the first screen after evaluating <script>'s?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

Suppose we have a very simple page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <p>Hello There</p>
</body>

<script>
    document.body.onload = function() {
        console.log("onload")
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        console.log("DOMContentLoaded");
    });
    console.log(document.body)
    document.body.innerHTML = ''
</script>
</html>
```

According to the console output, the document.body has been set before DOMContentLoaded, also the "Hello There" seems never been rendered to the viewport.

Please give me some hints or implementation ideas, since it is really hard for me to find some identified materials which could be applied for this case.

Thanks

Comment: "Running inline `<script>` tags" would be part of loading the DOM Content. This is why most of the "heavy lifting" is generally put in the `DOMContentLoaded` event, so that the only thing "blocking" the load is the preparation of that event handler, not its execution.

Comment: Thanks! But I am wondering why "document.body.innerHTML = ''" seems executes before "console.log(document.body)" which gives me the result that the <body> has been tweaked before printing the first screen?

Comment: You are logging `document.body`, which is an object. Logged objects are stored by reference, and when you expand the reference it gives you the "current" state at that point in time. If you insert `debugger;` just after `console.log` then you can expand it out before the overwrite.